# Ionic 4/Angular 6 : Testing API on localhost gets to "~ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic and Angular, and probably my question is primitive, but it would be helpful, if someone can help me and explain what is wrong!

I was just going through [this tutorial](https://www.djamware.com/post/5b5cffaf80aca707dd4f65aa/building-crud-mobile-app-using-ionic-4-angular-6-and-cordova), doing all the same and trying to understand the code. All was fine but at the final testing I got an error:

`OPTIONS http://localhost:1337/localhost:3000/api/classroom net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

And looks like another user also got it and posted comment, but it hasn't been solved. Can you help me with this?

BTW another user's error "Property 'location' does not exist on type 'DetailPage'." also exists, but well, this one is not so critical...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are running your backend on a different port than your frontend (Ionic). If you are using the standard settings of ionic your frontend is served from port 8100 (localhost:8100).

Your backend seems to be running at localhost:3000

Therefore when you are calling your are doing a [cross-origin request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)
For security reasons this call per default is not allowed on the server.
 In order to allow this you need to install a package like https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html (if you are using nodejs as backend) or https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers (if you are using django) or a similar package for your backend. 
The **OPTIONS** requests gets sent to your server before your actual request is sent to the server in a cross origin request. It basically asks the server if the operation that it wants to perform is allowed or not. Once you set up the the package for CORS handlling on your server successfully your api call should work.

Answer (score 0):

Error says clearly that it's not able to reach to backend API because you haven't started any.

it's mentioned in their tools required section. and also contains link of REST API source code.

please read tutorial again best of luck